# How do I get javascript to write to the screen every time a prompted input is entered?

Tags: javascript, html

My code is below.  My objective is to write a javascript code that will prompt a user to enter 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, or 0 to quit.  When you enter 1 or 2 for addition or subtraction it is supposed to write to the screen "You have selected addition (or subtraction)", then prompt you to enter first number, then second number, then displays the result " (num1) added to (num2) the result is (sum)", all under a title in blue with a goldenrod background(that part I figured out).  I am a javascript newby.  What is happening is that it is writing everything on to the screen all at once when I input the last number.  How do I get it to write each part to the screen as it is being input?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Jeremy's Assignment 4 Solution</title>

        <div style = "background-color:lightgoldenrodyellow; color: blue; text-align: center;">
            <script type = "text/javascript">
                <!--

                var now = new Date(); //current date and time
                var hour = now.getHours(); // current hour (0-23)

                // determine whether it's morning
                if (hour < 12 )
                    document.write( "<h2>Good Morning, " );

                 // determine whether the time is PM
                 if ( hour >= 12 )
                 {
                    // convert to a 12-hour clock
                    hour = (hour - 12);

                    //determine whether it is before 6 PM
                    if ( hour < 6 )
                        document.write( "<h2>Good Afternoon, " );

                    // determine whether it is after 6 PM
                    if ( hour >= 6 )
                    document.write( "<h2>Good Evening, " );
                 } // end if

                 document.writeln( " Welcome to Jeremy's Assignment 4 Solution.</h2>" );
                 // -->
            </script>
        </div>
        <div style = "text-align:center">
            <script type = "text/javascript">

                var choice = choice = window.prompt("Enter 1 for Addition, 2 for Subtraction, or 0 to Quit", "0");

                while (choice != 0) {


                    if (choice == 1) {
                        document.write("<p style='text-align:center;'>You have selected to perform Addition</p>");

                        // read in first number from user as a string
                        num1 = window.prompt("Enter first integer");

                        // read in second number from user as a string
                        num2 = window.prompt("Enter second integer");

                        //convert numbers from strings to integers
                        number1 = parseInt(num1);
                        number2 = parseInt(num2);

                        sum = number1 + number2; // add the numbers

                        //display the results
                        document.writeln("<p style='text-align:center;'> " + num1 + " added to " + num2 + " the result is " + sum + "</p>");
                    }
                    else if (choice == 2)
                    {
                        document.write("<p style='text-align:center;'>You have selected to perform Subtraction</p>");

                        // read in first number from user as a string
                        num1 = window.prompt("Enter first integer");

                        // read in second number from user as a string
                        num2 = window.prompt("Enter second integer");

                        //convert numbers from strings to integers
                        number1 = parseInt(num1);
                        number2 = parseInt(num2);

                        sum = number1 - number2; // add the numbers

                        //display the results
                        document.writeln("<p style='text-align:center;'> " + num1 + " subtracted from " + num2 + " the result is " + sum + "</p>");
                    }
                    else
                        (choice == 0)
                    {
                        document.write("<p style='text-align:center;'>You have selected to exit</p>");
                        break;
                    }
                }


            </script>
        </div>



    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Button to go to home page -->
        <p style="text-align: center">
         <button style="height:25px;width:100px" onclick="window.location='index.html'">HOME</button>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by " write each part to the screen as it is being input"? can you provide a sample output?

Comment: I think he wants to prompt for the first input, then output the first input, then prompt for the second input, then output the second input. You'd just need a few separate  `document.writeln` lines for that, placed in-between the prompts.

Comment: Basically, I mean When the screen first loads, it should already have the "Good Afternoon/ Morning/ Evening, Welcome to My Assignment 4" at the top of the page, then when you select Add, Subtract, or Quit, it should then write "You have selected Addition/ Subtraction/ to Quit" on the screen, then after you enter your two numbers it displays the results on the next line.  As it stands now, everything including the welcome line displays only after you click ok after entering your numbers, then it displays everything at once.